# How can I specify which value a enum can have based on the current value?

Tags: c#, enums

I am looking for a way to specify a lets call it Decision Tree or a Flow.

I have a Start value 1 or REQUESTED and this enum can have multiple following values like 2 or IN_PROGRESS or 3 or DECLINED.

And now only from the value 2 it should be possible to go to a higher value like 4 or FINISHED.

What is the most practically way to define the possible paths a process or flow can have?

Comment: A state machine of sorts,would be my suggestion

Comment: Have a class/function of the business rules defined. Call that with the current value and have all possible values with the next logical value returned first.

Comment: We used to use bitwise operations and an int for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's practical is often what's easiest to read an understand. To that end I recommend being explicit about what which states can lead to which other states. The `enum` is just a list of possible values. Using the `int` values of the `enum` might seem more concise, but it's harder to read and can lead to other problems.

First, here's an `enum` and a simple class that changes from one state to another if that change is allowed. (I didn't cover every state.)

```
enum RequestState
{
    Requested,
    InProgress,
    Declined,
    Finished
}

public class Request
{
    private RequestState _state = RequestState.Requested;

    public void BeginWork()
    {
        if (_state == RequestState.Declined || _state == RequestState.Finished)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can only begin work on a new request.");
        _state = RequestState.InProgress;
    }

    public void Decline()
    {
        if (_state == RequestState.Finished)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Too late - it's finished!");
        _state = RequestState.Declined;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

If we base it on the numeric value of `_state` and determine that the number can only go up, a few things can go wrong:

- Someone can rearrange the enums or add a new one, not knowing that the numeric value or position has logical significance. That's an easy mistake because that value usually isn't significant.
- You might need to implement logic that isn't quite so simple. You might need a state that can be preceded by some of the values before it but not all of them.
- You might realize that there's a valid reason for going backwards. What if a request is declined, and in the future you determine that you want to reopen requests, effectively sending them back to `Requested`?

If the way this is implemented starts out a little bit weird, those changes could make it even harder to change and follow. But if you just describe clearly what changes are possible given any state then it will be easy to read and modify.

Comment: Even though I answered the question more explicitly. In practice I would have gone more this route (and voted accordingly). I can imagine very few instances where iterating through the possible states would truly be the ultimate objective, but who knows!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something to leverage that enums are basically just integers:

```
private static Status NextState(Status status)
{
    var intOfStatus = ((int)status) + 1;
    return (Status)intOfStatus;
}
```

And some sample logic based on this approach:

```
public enum Status
{
    NotStarted = 0,
    Started = 1,
    InProgress = 2,
    Declined = 3
}
public static void Main()
{
    var curStatus = Status.NotStarted;

    Console.WriteLine(curStatus.ToString()); //writes 'NotStarted'

    if ((int)curStatus++ == (int)Status.Started)
    {
        curStatus = Status.Started; 
    }

    Console.WriteLine(NextState(curStatus)); //writes 'InProgress'
}
```